# Search for files based on a list of partial names and copy them to a destination folder using windows shell

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I am an absolute newbie to batch programming. I have posted this question after some amount of searching. Kindly guide me.
I have a folder containing a thousand images:

```
000001_x_abc1.jpg
000001_x_efg1.jpg
000001_x_hij1.jpg
000002_x_abc1.jpg
000002_x_efg1.jpg
000002_x_hij1.jpg
.
.
.
.
234562_x_abc2.jpg
234562_x_efg2.jpg
234562_x_hij2.jpg
```

Of theses files I have generated a 'list of files' that I need to pull out based on partial names i.e the numeric ID - first 6 numeric values in the file name e.g 234562*.jpg and copy them to a destination folder.

Note: Every numeric ID based search should give me 3 files and I need to copy all three. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried the following code based on my search:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "DEST_DIR=my_desination"
SET "SEARCH_DIR=my_source"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (%~dp0my_list.txt%) DO (
    FOR /R "%SEARCH_DIR%" %%f IN (*%%a*) DO (
        SET "SRC=%%~dpf"
        SET DEST=!SRC:%SEARCH_DIR%=%DEST_DIR%!
        xcopy /S /I "%%~f" "!DEST!"
    )
)
```

And my list file is as below:

> ```
> 002631_*.jpg
> 054741_*.jpg
> 054992_*.jpg
> 055053_*.jpg
> 055054_*.jpg
> 055118_*.jpg
> 055267_*.jpg
> 055294_*.jpg
> 055382_*.jpg
> 055415_*.jpg
> 055466_*.jpg
> 055546_*.jpg
> ```

Comment: what `a destination folder`? When I understand correctly, you'd need many of them.

Comment: @Stephan, I need to search for files based on a list that contains partial names and I need to copy all the files found (as a result of search.....may be recursively) into a destination folder.

Comment: all of them into the same destination?

Comment: @Stephan yes, all to the same directory

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you have trouble with? Please share your efforts! And show us the list file!

Comment: I cannot read that! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39286770/edit) your question and post it there (properly formatted)! and post also the list file there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing the list file contains full file patterns one per line, the following should work for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "SOURCEDIR=D:\Data"
set "TARGETDIR=D:\BackUp"
set "LISTFILE=D:\files.lst"

cd /D "%SOURCEDIR%" || exit /B 1
for /F "usebackq delims= eol=|" %%L in ("%LISTFILE%") do (
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B "%%L"') do (
       copy "%%~F" "%TARGETDIR%\%%~nxF"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Do I need to remove the 'underscore' from my list of file names ? Currently, it is : 055054_.jpg
Do I need to change it to: 055054.jpg
The query is because the batch file reports that the file is not found. Am I missing something ?

Comment: No, I thought the list file contains the numeric IDs only, like `055054`; Now since you edited the question and showed the true list entries (like `055054_*.jpg`), I adapted my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of copying specific files to a folder.

```
 @ECHO OFF
set "SOURCE_DIR=%userprofile%\Desktop\Source"
set "DEST_DIR=%userprofile%\Desktop\Output"
set "FILENAMES_TO_COPY=test.txt test1.txt test2.txt"

pushd "%SOURCE_DIR%"
for %%F IN (%FILENAMES_TO_COPY%) do (
    echo file "%%F"
    xcopy /Y "%%F" "%DEST_DIR%\"
)
popd
pause
```

The script copies `test.txt` `test1.txt` and `test2.txt` from the folder `Source`, to the folder `Output`

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822813/copy-specific-files-into-subfolder-in-batch) page

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ! I have at txt file that contains these partial names. How do I supply that instead of the names ?

Answer (score 0):

*(edited to reflect additional information in the question)*

```
for /f %%a in (partial.txt) do copy %%a "x:\destination folder\"
```

for every entry in the textfile copy `<entry from textfile>` to the destination.

see `for /?` for more details