# Batch file to upload files into SharePoint(by giving login details)

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a batch file which enables me to upload selected files(file names have got spaces in between) into the destination folder on SharePoint which is protected by password.

When I run this batch file, file names which I specified need to erase its older versions and move into that place. Also the files which are not matching should exist in the destination folder.

I got below code from :[Copy specific files into subfolder in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822813/copy-specific-files-into-subfolder-in-batch?newreg=6619c439d3e84bed901a5507e99d8b9d)

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Start Copy

set "SOURCE_DIR=C:\Users\paul.ikeda\Support\SNDataDemo91\SolidCAD\Inventor_in"
set "DEST_DIR=C:\Users\paul.ikeda\Support\SNDataDemo91\SolidCAD\Inventor_in\Files to Import"
set "FILENAMES_TO_COPY=SN_Router_1.ipt SN_Router_2.ipt SN_Router_3.ipt"

pushd "%SOURCE_DIR%"
for %%F IN (%FILENAMES_TO_COPY%) do (
    echo file "%%F"
    xcopy /Y "%%F" "%DEST_DIR%\"
)
popd
ECHO. done
pause
```

I need to add username/password somewhere in this code and if possible the code should accept file names with spaces in it.

Thank you

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I started with testing above code which I got from this site. When I tested using different files, I have noticed that files with file name contains spaces, not exporting to the destination folder. that is the draw back I have seen with the above code. Also, I need to add username/password enabled in this code, so that I can use to export to SharePoint.

Comment: The username/password.  Wouldn't that be better to use a mapping of a drive e.g. something like `Webdav`?   Then transfer what you need.  As for the spaces you need to add double quotes to the path.

Comment: Good suggestion, Yesterday I tried to setup a mapped drive. It didnot work. I have asked for Admin privileges. Once I get that, I will try again..

Comment: for test purpose, I have already tried on default mapped drive(network drive), it work for me. Once I get admin privlgs, will try with sharepoint mapped drive.